# Kubectl get svc command throws Access Denied error

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

Using AWS CLI and typing the command Kubectl get svc

throws the below error "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: Access denied"

Can anyone provide directions on what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

you should check RBAC roles and role bindings. verify the account that you are using has access to list the objects from api server

this is how you can check

```
master $ kubectl auth can-i get svc
yes
master $

master $  kubectl auth can-i create pods --all-namespaces
yes
master $
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was EKS Cluster was created with a different IAM role compared to Kubectl. Upon resolving the access credentials, kubectl was able to connect to Control Plane API Servers.